# Resize libgdx correctly after orientation changed

Tags: android, libgdx, orientation

I have some square images on the stage. For some reason they become rectangles after resize. How to resize them correctly? And how to manually resize the game?

landscape
[image: landscape]

portrait
[image: portrait]

As you see they have 230x230, so they can't be rectangles

```
   imagesEndPos[i] = new Image(skin1, "square");
                imagesEndPos[i].setWidth(230);
                imagesEndPos[i].setHeight(230);
                imagesEndPos[i].setPosition(pointIEnd.getX(), pointIEnd.getY());
                stage.addActor(imagesEndPos[i]);
```

create() method

```
   public void create() {
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        soundContainter=new SoundContainter();
        soundContainter.init(taskSheet,audios);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        camera.update();
}
```

resize() method

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().setScreenSize(width, height);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    if(width<height) {
        float w=camera.viewportWidth;
        float h=camera.viewportHeight;
        camera.viewportWidth = h;
        camera.viewportHeight = w;

    }else{
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
    }

    camera.update();
}
```

render()

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are cramming the picture. When it changes orientation be also sure to switch the camera.viewportWidth with the camera.viewportHeight

Comment: excuse me sir, where should i change the camera.veiwport? in resize method? I've updated the post, watch the code

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza change it when you also make the screen rotate

Comment: I've updated the resize method and still it didn't work